# GWT - RichTextArea: Using TAB-Key

Tags: gwt, richtext

I would like to use the tab-character within a RichTextArea in GWT. The usual behavior of pressing the tab-key is to switch the focus to the next element.
I am trying to capture the TAB-Key when typing text in a RichTextArea (via KeyDownHandler) and insert the tab character at the current cursor position. Sadly the RichTextArea has no getCursorPos/setCursorPos like the TextArea has.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You can try `richTextArea.getFormatter().insertHTML("\t")`, this should insert a tabulation on cursor position, or replace the current selection with a tabulation.

Comment: Sorry, i won't check if your answer is correct, we switched to rails a few months ago. Thanks anyway!